# jQuery trouble with .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, so, heres my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.topbuttons').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("margin-bottom", "65px").height(60).width(110);
    });
    $('.topbuttons').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).height(50).width(100);
    });
});
```

If I take out the .css("margin-bottom", "65px") everything works perfectly, the div(.topbuttons) gets bigger when its moused over. However the div below .topbuttons is pushed down each time .topbuttons height is increased. So I figured I could lower the bottom margin on .topbuttons by 10px, because we are increasing .topbuttons size by 10px. However it doesn't seem to work and I have no clue why. Please help

Comment: As @Roko C. Bulijan wrote, if is possible with css then just use css. ;)

Comment: Three answers thus far and lots of comments and still no jsfiddle...

Comment: @Dean.DePue I find http://jsBin.com better and faster to test and deploy. Any way a fiddle is not necessary (while good to have one) but the most important thing is to get the needed code to reproduce the issue, at least.

Answer (score 7):

I'd do it in pure CSS: **[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/powij/2/edit)**

```
.topbuttons{
   /* OTHER STYLES HERE*/
   height: 60px;
   width: 110px;
   margin-bottom:65px;
   transition: all 0.4s; /* if you want to apply some animation :) */
}
.topbuttons:hover{
   height: 50px;
   width: 100px;
   margin-bottom:75px; /* increase margin bottom if you don't want
                          to make move the div below*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use of .height and .width is wrong way with .css
Try this:

```
   $(this).css({'margin-bottom':'65px', width: '110px', height: '60px' });
```

Comment: `height(xy)` is a shorthand for `.css({height:xy })`

Comment: @Roko C.Buljan .i know this is a shorthand...but,acc to me if we're using .css,then we should write width & height in .css not seperate.

Answer (score 0):

If problem is with margin-bottom then why you not separate that line.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.topbuttons').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("margin-bottom", "65px");
        $(this).height(60).width(110);
    });
    $('.topbuttons').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).height(50).width(100);
    });
});
```

Or remove jquery and do it with css

```
.topbuttons:hover{
    margin-bottom:65px;
    height:60px;
    width:100px;
}
```

I recommended second options...

Comment: This is ok, but it doesn't address the OP's problem of having content pushed down when the button is hovered.

Comment: No he said that for push down issue he decrease bottom margin. For that he using bottom margin. He trying to do increse height 10px and decrease bottom margin 10px....

Comment: Really? *"If I take out the .css("margin-bottom", "65px") everything works perfectly, the div(.topbuttons) gets bigger when its moused over. **However the div below .topbuttons is pushed down each time .topbuttons height is increased**."*

Comment: @JayBlanchard "If I take out the .css("margin-bottom", "65px")"

Comment: @JayBlanchard He has `margin-bottom` taken out, hence the reason for that behavior. Again, he said only ***"If I take out the .css("margin-bottom", "65px")"***.

Comment: Chalk interpretation up to not enough coffee yet @SpencerWieczorek :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, my code ended up looking like this, in css:
    #topbuttonsrow a div:hover {
    color:maroon;
    background-color:#f05e35;
    height:60px;
    width:110px;
    margin:50px 25px 65px 25px;

#topbuttonsrow was a div around my 5 .topbuttons